# How to get the entirety of the content returned from a request, using the requests library in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, python-requests

I am using the requests library in Python to retrieve the CSV file available at [this URL](http://data-prod-cocorahs-org.azurewebsites.net/export/exportreports.aspx?ReportType=Daily&dtf=1&Format=CSV&ReportDateType=reportdate&Date=10/12/2023&TimesInGMT=False) (a 537kb weather data CSV). Each time I run the below code, the response length is slightly different. This results in the converted dataframe that is created from the returned data to have different number of rows each time.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = {url removed for brevity, same as above}
response = requests.get(url, timeout=2.50)
print(f"response length: {len(response.content)}")
content = response.content.decode('utf-8')
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(content), index_col=False)
```

Example responses after running the code two times consecutively:

```
response length: 1551255
11257
```

and,

```
response length: 1556748
11297
```

This example shows how the response length (and therefore number of rows read from CSV and converted into the pandas dataframe) vary each time. Is there a way to make sure requests gets the full response?

Comment: does anything change if you remove `timeout` param?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest no, nothing changes. I don't think timeout is even needed. Since the response is returning [200] almost right away, I don't think the timeout is helping. The problem is that the response happens fast, but the file probably needs a second or two to download.

Comment: Are you sure you're *not* getting the full document every time?  It could be dynamically generated from a real-time aggregated source, so that it is *natural* for later requests to return more data than earlier ones.

Comment: "*The problem is that the response happens fast, but the file probably needs a second or two to download*" -- **unlikely**.  The file is included *in* the response.  It's not a separate download.  If the file were being truncated because of a timing issue then that would constitute a serious flaw in `requests` (possible, but not likely), and you could expect to diagnose it by the downloaded file at least sometimes having an incomplete last line.

Comment: Well, I note that you claim in the question that the file size is 537kb, but the file I retrieved from that URL just now (manually) is about three times that size.  If the document is indeed dynamically generated then that doesn't mean the size must change for every request, and for this particular file, I would expect it not to change any further after some point.  Again, if the file were being erroneously truncated then you would expect to see the final row being truncated in the middle much of the time.

Answer (score 0):

Adjust your [timeout](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#timeouts) - 2.5 seconds is probably a bit low for an across the internet connection (keep in mind the TCP default packet retransmission window is 3 seconds)

Comment: I don't think timeout is even needed. Since the response is returning [200] almost right away, I don't think the timeout is helping. The problem is that the response happens fast, but the file probably needs a second or two to download. When I increase the timeout param to 10 seconds, the response length is still inconsistent.

Comment: Looks fine to me, actually - It is simply adding data to the file more quickly than you are requesting it. Every request I sent is returning a larger file, with more records in it